# Does P&T Assets work with Rackspace cloudfiles?

Tags: add-on, assets

I have noticed that [Pixel & Tonic Assets](http://pixelandtonic.com/assets) add-on explicitly states compatibility with Amazon S3.  We use Rackspace for our site and are expanding to CloudFiles to take advantage of the integrated CDN. Is Assets an option here?

The only other add-on I have seen on devotee was [Rackspace Cloudfiles](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/rackspace-cloudfiles).  I have used many P&T add-ons before.  Just trying to figure out what my options are here.

Ideally if someone has used one or both of these add-ons with CloudFiles, I would love to hear from you. Can I manage other types of assets like PDFs?

Thanks for any information you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We use Rackspace for our site and are expanding to CloudFiles to take advantage of the integrated CDN. Is Assets an option here?

No. Assets only works with the local file system and Amazon S3.

> Can I manage other types of assets like PDFs?

Yes, you can manage any type of file with Assets.

Answer (score 1):

I recently switched from Assets to Dev Demon's Channel Files on one project to gain Amazon S3 support. Unfortunately it was just a few weeks before Assets support for S3 was announced. I'm a big Assets fan.

[Dev Demon's Channel Files](http://www.devdemon.com/channel_files/) appears to support Rackspace Cloud if you don't find support with Assets.

Comment: Mark, I appreciate the suggestion - unfortunately my reputation doesn't carry over from stackoverflow to here, so I cannot yet give you an up vote for the help yet.  Will do so when reputation allows for this.

Comment: Do you know if this would work with image sizer plugin?

Comment: I can't say for sure. I typically rely on CE Image for image resizing, and I've used CE Image for on images output via Assets. I've only started using Channel Files, and we're using it for PDFs. I don't see why an image processor wouldn't work on the output of these tags.

Answer (score 0):

The whole codebase was re-engineered for Assets 2 to enable multiple source types, so Rackspace Cloud will be coming in the future, but we don't have an ETA on that yet.